# I need a way to mailto with a file that is attached to the Notes document

Tags: xpages

So I have an xpage that displays with attachments on the Notes document.  I need a button to mailto an attachment that is ON the document, not on a hard drive somewhere.  Is there a way to do that without detaching the file?

Comment: So if I understand this correctly you have Notes documents with attachments that you want to send by mail? That's possible by reading the attachment through the EmbeddedObject class and add them to a Mime message. One of my XSnippets can do that (https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=create-html-mails-in-ssjs-using-mime).

Answer (score 2):

The standard mailto: protocol link that is commonly used to launch the user's default email program with a pre-filled subject / address, does not support attaching files.
Here is the [RFC 2368](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt) in which the protocol was first described.

If the recipient is an internal user who also has access to the XPages application, then you may be able to use mailto: to include a link to the attachment in the 'body' of the email (using the body parameter of the mailto link). You would use the Attachment URL method [described in Stepan Wissel's blog post](https://wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-86QKNM).

Otherwise if it is a requirement that the attachment is actually attached to the email, you can make a button that will make the Domino server send an email with the attachment, on the user's behalf. That is possible using [the technique that Mark Leusink](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=create-html-mails-in-ssjs-using-mime) suggested in the comments above.